# How do I modify the “deep” background when using an iOS 13-style modal in React Navigation?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I have been following the `react-navigation` getting started guide. I’ve not modified anything beyond adding...

```
options={{
   ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
   cardOverlayEnabled: true,
   gestureEnabled: true,
   headerShown: false
}}
```

...to the modal to make it look like iOS 13.

It works and animates great, but I’d like the back-background to be black. In the screenshot below, I’m talking about the darkest grey color that the time and battery icons are on.

[image: Screenshot of Dark Grey Background]

I tried setting the background of the Theme to black, but that made all the cards black. Is there a way to only make that far-far background black?

I’m sure I’m not being clear, but thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your navigator into a View like this:

```
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "black",
    flex: 1,
  }}
> 
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {/* Your screens */}
  </Stack.Navigator>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

if i get your question right it's about the theme color, which you can find in the index.HTML file.
You should see a meta tag in the head which looks something like this:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
```

Let me know if i got it right.